# VBA: How to deal with an empty array from reading an XML file

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm reading an XML file in VBA and then using that to extract some information to create another Output XML file. I only need to generate amn output file when the fields in the initial XML file are filled in.

Currently when it gets to an empty tag it fails. I've tried some of the empty array solutions I've found on here but they don't seem to work. Is my code that bad??

```
Private Sub gDialer()
    For i = 7 To 30000
        If Sheets("Latest Report").Cells(i, "AL").Value = "Active - G to sign" Then
            If Sheets("Latest Report").Cells(i, "AJ").Value <> "" Then
                GenerateReadXML "Z:\AReports\A\Reports\readXML\gRead" & i & ".xml", Sheets("Latest Report").Cells(i, "AJ").Value
                sendXML "readXML\gRead" & i & ".xml", "gRead" & i & "response", "Read"

                Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
                XMLFileName = "Z:\AReports\A\Reports\fActivities\results\gRead" & i & "response.xml"
                'MsgBox XMLFileName
                oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
                Set Numnode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/result/data29/text()")
                Set titleNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/result/data25/text()")
                Set firstNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/result/data26/text()")
                Set lastNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/result/data27/text()")

                On Error GoTo didntfindit
                Dim numStr As String
                Dim titleStr As String
                Dim firstStr As String
                Dim lastStr As String

                '### here's where it fails ###

                numStr = Numnode(0).NodeValue
                titleStr = titleNode(0).NodeValue
                firstStr = firstNode(0).NodeValue
                lastStr = lastNode(0).NodeValue

                GenerateDialerXML "Z:\AReports\A\Reports\dialerXML\dialer" & i & ".xml", Numnode(0).NodeValue, titleNode(0).NodeValue, firstNode(0).NodeValue, lastNode(0).NodeValue, Sheets("Latest Report").Cells(i, "AJ").Value, 87
                sendDialerXML "dialer" & i & ".xml", sendHandshake, "gDResponse"
didntfindit:
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

When it fails, it's because the XML is like this:

```
<data24>something</data24>
</data25>
</data26>
</data27>
<data28>something else</data28>
</data29>
```

It works fine when there are values, but I can't figure out the next step.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it now, here's what I came up with, hope this helps someone one day:

```
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
Set numNode = oXMLFile.getElementsByTagName("data29")
Set titleNode = oXMLFile.getElementsByTagName("data25")
Set firstNode = oXMLFile.getElementsByTagName("data26")
Set lastNode = oXMLFile.getElementsByTagName("data27")

On Error GoTo didntfindit

Dim numStr As String
Dim titleStr As String
Dim firstStr As String
Dim lastStr As String

numStr = numNode(0).Text
titleStr = titleNode(0).Text
firstStr = firstNode(0).Text
lastStr = lastNode(0).Text
```